# Call to a member function move() on null laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I am new to Laravel, I am getting this error "Call to a member function move() on null laravel 9" and can't understand what is going wrong here, could you help ? My Column name in the table is **productimage**

**Product.Blade.php**

```
<form action="{{url('/add_product')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf       
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
 <label for="">Product Image</label>
 <input type="file" name="proimage">
 </div>
</form>
```

**AdminController.php**

```
use App\Models\products;
public function add_product(Request $request){
$product = new products;
    $image = $request->proimage;
    $imagename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->productimage->move('proimagefolder', $imagename);
    $product->productimage=$imagename; 
    $product->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Product Added Successfully');
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `$request->productimage`? Two lines above, you access `$request->proimage`

Comment: can't understand, is this right or wrong?